# Android getIntent().getExtras() NullPointerException

Tags: java, android

In my application i have three Activities : A,B,C.

Activity A includes listview with @OnItemClick that starts Activity B and sends Extras to it.

In Activity B i getExtras in OnCreate(), so everytime activity starts it tries to get those values. The problem is that they are not always there, for example when coming back from Activity C (because list item in Activity A was not clicked).

What would be the best way to deal with getting extras with this kind of workflow?

EDIT: The extras im sending are item list position.

Comment: Check where are you coming from.:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If what you're trying to do is get rid of the nullpointer error try checking to see if the key for the value you are trying to get exists.

```
Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
if (extras != null) {
    if (extras.containsKey("isNewItem")) {
        boolean isNew = extras.getBoolean("isNewItem", false);

        // do something with these values
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is it. I was trying to make condition for it, but only with variable that should get extras value. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Pass your all extras to all of your activities A,B,C in order not to lose them.

Comment: It's not about the extras itself, more about the exception that is crushing my application. If not in onCreate, where or how should i get them?